# Angular5 / PrimeNG - p-listbox - onDblClick - event issue

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I tried to use p-listbox - onDblClick - event and it is not returning the selected list element.

Instead the event object only has the this value,

```
{"originalEvent":{"isTrusted":true}}
```

HTML

Blockquote

```
<!-- Selected Tables -->
<p-listbox [options]="selectedTables" (onDblClick)="tableListBoxSelectEvent($event)" [listStyle]="{'min-height':'100px','max-height':'100px'}">
    <ng-template let-table pTemplate="item">
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
            <span style="float:left;">{{table.tableLabel}}</span>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-listbox>
```

Typescript

```
// Table select event from the Selected tables list box
tableListBoxSelectEvent(event) {
  console.log('this.choosenTable >> ' + JSON.stringify(event));
}
```

Reference: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/listbox

Update:-

My 'selectedTables' JSON object is as below,

```
 dummy3 = [
    {
    "reportType": "COREP ALM",
    "startDate": "31-12-2016",
    "endDate": "30-03-2018",
    "tableId": 369,
    "tableCode": "C 69.00.w",
    "tableLabel": "Prices for various lengths of funding. Significant currencies"
  }, {
    "reportType": "COREP ALM2",
    "startDate": "30-06-2015",
    "endDate": "30-03-2018",
    "tableId": 372,
    "tableCode": "C 71.00.a",
    "tableLabel": "Concentration of counterbalancing capacity by issuer/counterparty. Total"
  }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working solution. Check out the **plunker** that prints the **selected list element** that is being clicked on:

**NOTE:** Make sure to open up **Dev Tools** to see the value of the element after doing double click.

If you want to print the value just do this:

```
console.log('this.choosenTable >> ' + JSON.stringify(event.value));
```

**Working solution:** [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/h9XVAdLWEuHc24F1iD6x?p=preview)

```
<p-listbox [options]="selectedTables" (onDblClick)="tableListBoxSelectEvent($event)" [listStyle]="{'min-height':'100px','max-height':'100px'}">
<ng-template let-table pTemplate="item">
    <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
        <span style="float:left;">{{table.tableLabel}}</span>
    </div>
</ng-template>
</p-listbox>
```

Comment: Thanks. But event.value prints as undefined. Because event just has the value {"originalEvent":{"isTrusted":true}}, which does not have a key called value in it.

Comment: Did it worked for you? Do u have the working code? I am using PrimeNG 5.2.0.

Comment: Many thanks, it works in your plunker code, but not in mine. Would investigate.

Comment: It turns out that I don't have a field called value in my JSON which I posted in the question now.  Hence it did nt work properly. After I added that it works. Many thanks for the help to fix this.

Comment: The plunker example doesn't run.  It's stuck on "loading..."